# JQuery Mobile load Ajax Error

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to load a page stored in my phone memory into the DOM.

```
<div data-role="page" id="portail" data-dom-cache="true">
  <a data-role="button" id="testButton">test button</a>
</div>
```

And my JQuery function :

```
$("#testButton").click( function() {
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load","file:///sdcard/TRISKALIA/Module_Test/test.html");
});
```

I get the following error in my JS Console :

```
GET file:///sdcard/TRISKALIA/Module_Test/test.html  jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
    k.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
    n.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
    a.widget.load jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js:5201
    (anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js:927
    (anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js:1025
    n.extend.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
    n.fn.n.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
    a.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js:1011
    (anonymous function) index.js:3
    n.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
    r.handle jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
```

I don't know what I'm missing, I'm sure it's some kind of dumb error but I can't find it, please help me ! Thanks.